# Double records inserted when tracking image views

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Here is my code for tracking image views (tracks.php script):

```
$img_id = $_GET['img_id'];
$db->insert(TRACKS, $img_id);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
//then output img's content
```

When I'm using `header()` function and output the image's content, the record is duplicated.
I don't know why?

Please help me out. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons this could be happening that I would have a hard time tracking down without running a few tests and knowing more about the $db object.

→ A simple solution to the problem would be to check to make sure the $img_id doesn't already exists in the database before inserting it.

Using the **Zend DB** $db object to check for the img_id first should work something like this:

```
$select = $db->select();
$select->from( 'table_name', '*' );
$select->where( 'img_id = ?', $img_id );

$rows = $db->fetchAll( $select );

if( count( $rows[0] ) == 0 ) { $db->insert( TRACKS, $img_id ); }
```

making sure to *sanitize* $img_id first to keep [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) off your back.

→ Then check the [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) / [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) returned. If the number returned is equal to 0, then insert the $img_id. Else, don't insert it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The $db object is extended from Zend_DB class. When I remove header() function and not outputting the image's content, the record is inserted properly.

Comment: What happens if you put the $_GET and $db->insert below the header() call?

Comment: Try the updated answer above, I adapted it to use Zend's DB object as best as I could. @QuanNguyen

Comment: Thank you. I switch the browser to Google Chrome and the problem gone away. Haha. Say bye-bye to FireFox :))

Comment: Really? the underlying problem may be that Firefox caches the image differently than Chrome, and since the image is output by your php code, it must be re-running the PHP code while caching the image. For cross-browser compatibility, I would still perform the check before inserting the img_id if possible.